# Operator Product Expansions using the stress energy tensor

Tags: operators, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'm reading "String Theory Demystified" by David McMahon. On p.111 of the book, it is asserted that:

> One operator product expansion of particular interest involves the energy-momentum tensor. In the complex plane: $$T_{zz}(z)= \ :\eta_{\mu \nu} \partial_z X^\mu \partial_z X^\nu:$$

where the $:$ indicates time ordering.

Then using this result, follows the computation of the OPE of the radially ordered product $T_{zz}(z) \partial_w X^\rho (w)$:

> $$\langle R(T_{zz}(z)\partial_wX^\phi(w))\rangle = R(:\eta_{\mu\nu} \partial_z X^\mu(z) \partial_z X^\nu(z): \partial_wX^\rho (w) )\\
> =\eta_{\mu\nu} \langle \partial_zX^\mu (z) \partial_wX^\rho(w)\rangle\partial_zX^\nu (z) \\+
> \eta_{\mu\nu}\langle\partial_zX^\nu(z)\partial_wX^\rho(w)\rangle \partial_z X^\mu(z)$$

However, I don't understand the second equality in this equation. What are the rules to deduce this?  I see obviously why the metric just comes out as it is treated as a constant but I don't quite get what is going with the operators.

Comment: Do you understand how to do Wick contractions?

Comment: Yes, so this is Wick contraction of the normally ordered fields with the non-normally ordered fields? In other words, we have two possible contractions with fields inside the normal ordering operators?

Comment: yes, this is just plain old Wick contraction. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems that this just Wick contracting the normally ordered fields with those that are not. So we obtain two possible contractions, which give the expressions in my question.